# serverless framework local testing with layers

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to create a serverless framework template from our current SAM template due to a provider migration but have run into an issue importing our custom library in the serverless.yml file. The error in question is in the function's import statement, saying "no module named dal", implying the layer is not being propperly attached to the function. The content that's to be in the layer is a package in the same project as can be seen below.

The current project structure ressembles the following:

```
project/

functions/
  user/
    create/
      main.py
  function2/
    ...

libraries/
  dal/
    python/
      dal/
        __init__.py
        dal.py
  lib2/
  ...
```

This is the my progress in the serverless.yml file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.11

layers:
  Dal:
    path: libraries/dal

functions:
  appUserCreate:
    handler: functions/user/create/main.lambda_handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: /user/create
          method: post

    layers:
      - !Ref DalLambdaLayer
...
```

This is the current SAM template.yaml working implementation:

```
DAL:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
  Properties:
    ContentUri: libraries/dal
    CompatibleRuntimes:
      - python3.11
  Metadata:
    BuildMethod: python3.11

UserCreate:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: functions/user/create/
    Handler: main.lambda_handler
    Runtime: python3.11
    Architectures:
      - x86_64

     Layers:
      - !Ref DAL

     Events:
      UserCreateEndpoint:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /user/create
          Method: post
```

I've tried changing the layer's path to libraries/dal/dal to no avail, same with ./libraries/dal and ./libraries/dal/dal.

I'm testing locally using the serverless-offline plugin, as I'm unable to deploy to the cloud for the time being. The plugin serverless-python-requirements has yielded no results either.